# {!ApprovalRequest.Comments} in lightning email templates

Tags: lightning, email-template, approval-process

i am trying to transform all hte classic email template that i have to lightning email templates,

and i can't figure out how to change **{!ApprovalRequest.Comments}** i've tried **{{{ApprovalRequest.Comments}}}** but it doesn't work,

any suggestions on how to do it please ?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: in the dev console logs i don't see any errors, i just don't receive the email alert while using it in an approval process, when i remove it i receive the email

Comment: check the entry criteria  is satisfied or not for approval process step to send an email?

Comment: it is satisfied, when i remove {{{ApprovalRequest.Comments}}} it works, 

i want to have the comment when i approve or reject the approval request ! in the classic template it works with {!ApprovalRequest.Comments }.

Comment: try this formula in the email template. {!IF ApprovalRequest.Comments = 'Submitted for approval',NULL,ApprovalRequest.Comments)}

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do cannot be done in Lightning Email Templates. You will have to use Classic Email Templates if you want to include any merge fields related to Approval Processes. It does not matter if you use the HML syntax.

Comment: @identigral How does it not answer the question? If the question literally cannot be done, that is the answer, is it not?